# jquery mobile mobile ListView cannot load the page

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

```
    <div data-role="header"  >
        <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
    </div>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" id="listview" name="listview">

        <li>
            <a href="#">Xavier</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Zachary</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"  >Zoe</a>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- /listview -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#listview').on('click', 'a', function() {

            $.mobile.loadPage("us.html");

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

i created list view by using jquery mobile .It works fine as i expected.But i need to load page when i click a item in a list view.Can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot load page in jquery mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269189/cannot-load-page-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: you have asked this question before and I gave you a hint with no response from your side whatsoever. Please refrain from asking the same question twice. Be patient, someone will help you. Please delete either this question.

Comment: no it is not working  on Android tab either.

Comment: if want to show a page use `$.mobile.changePage("us.html");`

Comment: i tried it but i want to add that page on to a specific div on index page and what is the difference between change page and load page